# Google API quota usage conditions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm looking for ways to overcome API quotas without resorting to requesting a raise, and would like to know what is classified as `.. per user`.

For example:

- Google People API has this quota: `Read Requests per 100 seconds per user`
- I setup an OAuth Client ID: `123-5ampl3.apps.googleusercontent.com`
- And for whatever reason, my queries are going to exceed "100 seconds per user".

My question/concerns:

1. Can I create another client ID `123-an0th3r.apps.googleusercontent.com` and have both call the same API so that I now essentially have `requests per 200 seconds per user`?
2. Or is `per user` not tied to the client IDs, but instead, to the project id.
3. Could I create another project and re-route extra API calls to there?
4. Or must I throttle my querying so it stays within the limit.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about interpreting the terms, conditions, and pricing models of a hosted service, not programming.

Comment: It's about figuring out a very popular API. There's ambiguity in the API's documentation about what a user is. Definitely a programming question.